# How to return an array of structs properly (in this codewars example)?

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I've been stuck on this particular codewars exercise for a while now. Not because the puzzle itself is hard (no, I was able to print the correct results after only a few minutes), but because I can't seem to figure out how to return the result.

I'm supposed to return an array of structs. I know I can't just statically allocate it and then return it. I must dynamically allocate memory and return the pointer. I do this like this (n-m is the max amount of structs I might have to return):

```
Pair* res = malloc((n-m)*sizeof(Pair));
```

I then assign values as follows:

```
res[t].first = i;
res[t].snd = sum;
```

And then return the array:

```
return res;
```

If I print the whole array before returning it, it appears filled. But the codewars system says I returned an empty array? 
I was able to fix this by adding an ampersand to return the address. By doing this, it returns the first struct properly (I was able to figure this out by adding manual checks), but the second struct would be rubbish data.

Anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Here's the full function (removed the calculations because they're irrelevant to the problem, and also might spoil the puzzle for others who stumble upon this question while solving it):

```
Pair** listSquared(long long m, long long n, int* length) {
    Pair* res = malloc((n-m)*sizeof(Pair));
    int t = 0;
    long long sum = 0;

    for(int i = m; i<=n; i++)
    {
      if(sum = isSumSquare(i))
      {
        res[t].first = i;
        res[t].snd = sum;
        t++;
      }
    }

    *length = t;

    return res;
}
```

One more thing: I did notice that the return type is Pair**. I'm guessing this is what I'm doing wrong, but I also tried making the datatype of res Pair** (and then replacing the . with -> when assigning), and/or taking the sizeof(Pair*) instead of just Pair. I tried more combinations than I can count, but still haven't gotten anything that works. I have a feeling I'm missing something fundamental knowledge about pointers here...

Anyone who can tell me what I'm doing wrong?

edit: as requested by Gilles, the exact problem statement: https://i.stack.imgur.com/chdRE.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above, `type` controls everything. You were given a function prototype with `Pair **listSquared (...)`. The function must return type `Pair**` (e.g. a *pointer-to-pointer* to type `Pair`)

Returning a *pointer-to-pointer* to dynamically allocated object requires first declaring the object of type `Pair**` within `listSquared` and allocating the number of pointers required, e.g.

```
    Pair **res = malloc ((n-m) * sizeof *res);
```

(**note:** if you always set your *typesize* by using the dereferenced pointer, `sizeof *res` instead of `sizeof (Pair*)`, there is no way you can get it wrong)

Then within your function in the loop where you fill each `struct Pair`, you first need to allocate a block of memory for each struct and assign the beginning address for that block to your pointer, e.g.

```
        res[t] = malloc (sizeof *res[t]);
```

In each case, and with EVERY allocation, you need to ***validate*** that the allocation succeeded before attempting to make use of the pointers or block of memory. For example:

```
    if (!res) {                 /* validate EVERY allocation */
        perror ("malloc-res");
        *length = 0;            /* set length zero */
        return NULL;            /* return NULL indicating failure */
    }
```

and in the case of failure allocating for `res[t]`, you need to `free()` each previously allocated struct **and** the pointers before returning to avoid creating a memory leak, e.g.

```
        if(sum = isSumSquare(i))
        {   /* allocate for res[t] and validate, free all on failure */
            if (!(res[t] = malloc (sizeof *res[t]))) {
                perror ("malloc-res[t]");
                while (t--)         /* free previously allocated structs */
                    free (res[t]);
                free (res);         /* free pointers */
                *length = 0;        /* set length zero */
                return NULL;        /* return NULL indicating failure */
            }
            res[t].first = i;
            res[t].snd = sum;
            t++;
        }
```

Based on my best understanding of what you needed to do, you could put it altogether with something like:

```
Pair **listSquared (long long m, long long n, int *length)
{
    Pair **res = malloc ((n-m) * sizeof *res);
    int t = 0;
    long long sum = 0;

    if (!res) {                 /* validate EVERY allocation */
        perror ("malloc-res");
        *length = 0;            /* set length zero */
        return NULL;            /* return NULL indicating failure */
    }

    for(int i = m; i<=n; i++)
    {
        if(sum = isSumSquare(i))
        {   /* allocate for res[t] and validate, free all on failure */
            if (!(res[t] = malloc (sizeof *res[t]))) {
                perror ("malloc-res[t]");
                while (t--)         /* free previously allocated structs */
                    free (res[t]);
                free (res);         /* free pointers */
                *length = 0;        /* set length zero */
                return NULL;        /* return NULL indicating failure */
            }
            res[t].first = i;
            res[t].snd = sum;
            t++;
        }
    }

    *length = t;

    return res;
}
```

In the case of allocation failure your function returns `NULL` and has freed any memory it had allocated up to the point of failure eliminating all potential memory leaks.

I'm glad you got things working and have submitted your code. If you have any questions about the reasoning above, just drop a comment and I'm happy to help further.